# Write an explicit formula for an algebraic curve containing $x=t^2+1, y=t^3+t$ and sketch it.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is an exercise from Artin's *Algebra* but he doesn't provide any examples of how to do this. I just know that an algebraic curve is the set of zeroes for the polynomial. Looking for guidance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need to eliminate $t$ from the equations. We have 
$$
y = t(t^2+1) = tx\Rightarrow y^2 = x^2(x-1).
$$

[image]

(Note that the axes cross at (2,0))